# Building repo with Karaf features-maven-plugin with CXF dependency causes infinite loop

Tags: java, maven, cxf, circular-dependency, apache-karaf

Building repo with Karaf features-maven-plugin with CXF dependency causes infinite loop.

I'm using version 2.3.12 of the org.apache.karaf.tooling/features-maven-plugin.

this seems to have started happening with CXF version 3.2.x when the circular-dependency was added between cxf-core and cxf-commands.

It outputs hundreds of these, then throws a stack overflow exception:

```
[INFO] Adding contents for feature: cxf-core/3.2.14
[INFO] Adding contents for feature: cxf-commands/3.2.14
[INFO] Adding contents for feature: cxf-core/3.2.14
[INFO] Adding contents for feature: cxf-commands/3.2.14
```

here is the pom plugin section of my pom:

```
                <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>features-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.4</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                            <artifactId>wagon-http-lightweight</artifactId>
                            <version>3.4.1</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-features-to-repo</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-features-to-repo</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <features>
                                <feature>cxf-core/3.2.14</feature>
                            </features>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

here is the offending bit of the cxf features - notice that "cxf-core" has a conditional dependency on "cxf-commands" feature and "cxf-commands" feature has a hard dependency on "cxf-core".  This seems WRONG to me and I don't see any way of telling the plugin to not get into an infinite loop.

```
    <feature name="cxf-core" version="3.2.14">
        <feature version="3.2.14">cxf-specs</feature>
        <bundle start-level="30" dependency="true">mvn:org.apache.ws.xmlschema/xmlschema-core/2.2.5</bundle>
        <bundle start-level="25" dependency="true">mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlresolver/1.2_5</bundle>
        <bundle start-level="30" dependency="true">mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.fastinfoset/1.2.13_1</bundle>
        <bundle start-level="40">mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-core/3.2.14</bundle>
        <bundle start-level="40">mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-management/3.2.14</bundle>
        <conditional>
            <condition>shell</condition>
            <feature version="3.2.14">cxf-commands</feature>
        </conditional>
    </feature>
    <feature name="cxf-commands" version="3.2.14">
        <feature>shell</feature>
        <feature version="3.2.14">cxf-core</feature>
        <bundle start-level="40">mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/cxf-karaf-commands/3.2.14</bundle>
    </feature>
```

Answer (score 1):

well, as it turns out, the features-maven-plugin has been superseded.  This plugin works!

```
                <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

simply change the goal to: features-add-to-repository and make sure the  is set.  this is the normal one:

```
<repository>target/features-repo</repository>
```

and, it recognizes and supports the conditional functionality!